# How can I check for successful execution of last call of system()

Tags: c, linux

Here I want to know the status of the last executed call of `system()`.

I have one script file containing

```
hciconfig hci0 &> /dev/null
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
. ./$BT_CLEAN
```

I want to do same thing in a C Program so I used `system()` to run the command `hciconfig hci0 &> 
/dev/null`. But how can I know the status of this executed command? In the shell script we used "$?" same here In C: How can I know whether the last command was executed successfully or not?

I used `system("hciconfig hci0 &> /dev/null")` in C.

Comment: You are slightly confusing the terminology. "System call" is any function that is, wholly or mostly, implemented in the kernel. For example `open()`, `read()`, `fork()`, `exec()` etc. The `system()` function is not one, but wrapper around three of them, `fork()`, `exec()` and `waitpid()`. The command you run from a shell is normally called a "shell utility" or "external command".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote `man 3 system`:

> `system()` returns `-1` on error (e.g. `fork(2)`  failed),  **and  the
>          return  status  of the command otherwise.**

Comment: means system call it self return -1 if its fail?

Comment: @user1089679: No, it returns the same value as `$?` does in shell, that is 0 on success and usually +1 (but may be more) on failure. It only returns -1 if the `fork` call fails, which only happens if the system is in big trouble.